# In present indefinite tense s and es

Tags: tenses, present-tense

I have confusion about “Present Indefinite Tense”. I have learned that in case of “He, she, it and name” we will add s or es to verb. In some sentences I see that for non-living things also s is added to verb and sometimes for non-living thing verb is without s. I have no clear concept about this point. your guidance will be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add an s to the end of a verb only when the subject is in third-person singular form. The third-person singular includes pronouns like he, she, it, one and all singular nouns. As for the latter, there are, of course, millions of those as opposed to the former, the third-singular pronouns, of which there are only four in Modern English, as far as I know. Singular nouns are nouns that represent living or non-living things when there is only one instance of them. It can be absolutely anything: inanimate things, people, concepts, animals, names and even movie titles. For example: a book, a girl, love, a snake, John, *The Great Gatsby*.